# Distributing MS Access Application

Tags: ms-access

How can I distribute a MS Access application (database) in a professional way?

I will be using NSIS to create an installation package. 
I will be using a C# Application I created as a launcher for the access database file. 
But when I open the access file, I am presented with the **yellow security bar** at the top, which warns about active content. That is not professional.

Please help!

Comment: That's because YOU'RE not professional, not because of something wrong with Access. To avoid the warning, you need to set various registry keys and properties to set macro security. In A2007 and later you may need to set trusted locations (though I'm not sure that can be done without a UAC prompt). If you start an Access instance with COM automation, you can also set some of these properties for that particular instance instead of changing them permanently. That should be enough for you to get started on upping your level of professionalism.

Comment: .. and of course, check out http://www.sagekey.com/installation_access.aspx .  Hi David -- it's been a while!

Comment: Have you ever considerate to use another plataform? If you want to a "more proffessional" way, why didn't you use vb.net with SQL Server? The express editions are free and the environment is not so strange for Access developers. It's worth to invest some time learning how. Think about it!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I managed to fix the issue using registry keys like you mentioned. Just Googled for it. I am also using InnoSetup since this seems to be a bit easier on me. As for switching to vb.net, actually I am a C# developer, and I have worked with FoxPro. FoxPro has been phased out so nevermind that, C# however is an option, but my problem is that the huge amount of time it takes to develop something, and the unneeded complexity. MS Access is much much simpler, and much faster at getting results. It's almost like day and night for me really.

Comment: I write code in C# and have to break my head to get it to work the way I want. In MS Access whatever I write just seems to work! It's almost like Access can infer my intentions.

Answer (score 0):

Ms Access allows you to disable macros security just for that databae.
How?

Click the Microsoft Office Button and then click Access Options.

Click Trust Center, click Trust Center Settings, and then click Macro Settings.

There will be several options. You should click this one:

Enable all macros (not recommended, potentially dangerous code can run) Click this option to allow all macros to run.

After that you have to restart you ms access database.

The only con. about that is that you have to execute this process in every client computer. Because that setting depends on ms access instalation of the computer.

Hope it helps